# svg animation and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, svg

I have SVG animation, and its works fine in browser, but it doesn't work, when I'm using it in my program.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="preloader" data-name="preloader" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 150">
<rect width="800" height="150" fill="#ffffff"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="799" height="149" fill="#ffffff"/>
  
 
<circle cx="0" cy="75" r="4" fill="white">
    <animate id="color1_1" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.7s;move3_2.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_1" attributeName="cx" from="153" to="337" dur="1s" begin="0.7s;move3_2.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_1" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_1.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_1" attributeName="cx" from="337" to="337" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_1.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_1" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_2.end+0.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move3_1" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_2.end+0.1s" from="337" to="521" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle>

<circle cx="15" cy="75" r="4" fill="white"> 
    <animate id="color1_2" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.6s;move3_3.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_2" attributeName="cx" from="171" to="355" dur="1s" begin="0.6s;move3_3.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_2" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_2.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_2" attributeName="cx" from="355" to="355" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_2.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_2" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_3.end+0.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move3_2" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_3.end+0.1s" from="355" to="539" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle>

<circle cx="30" cy="75" r="4" fill="white"> 
    <animate id="color1_3" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.5s;move3_4.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_3" attributeName="cx" from="189" to="373" dur="1s" begin="0.5s;move3_4.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_3" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_3.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_3" attributeName="cx" from="373" to="373" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_3.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_3" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_4.end+0.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move3_3" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_4.end+0.1s" from="373" to="557" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle>

<circle cx="45" cy="75" r="4" fill="white">
    <animate id="color1_4" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.4s;move3_5.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_4" attributeName="cx" from="207" to="391" dur="1s" begin="0.4s;move3_5.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_4" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_4.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_4" attributeName="cx" from="391" to="391" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_4.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_4" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_5.end+0.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move3_4" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_5.end+0.1s" from="391" to="575" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle> 

<circle cx="60" cy="75" r="4" fill="white">
    <animate id="color1_5" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.3s;move3_6.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_5" attributeName="cx" from="225" to="409" dur="1s" begin="0.3s;move3_6.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_5" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_5.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_5" attributeName="cx" from="409" to="409" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_5.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_5" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_6.end+0.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move3_5" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_6.end+0.1s" from="409" to="593" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle>

<circle cx="75" cy="75" r="4" fill="white">
    <animate id="color1_6" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.2s;move3_7.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_6" attributeName="cx" from="243" to="427" dur="1s" begin="0.2s;move3_7.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_6" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_6.end" />
    <animate id="move2_6" attributeName="cx" from="427" to="427" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_6.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_6" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_7.end+0.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move3_6" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_7.end+0.1s" from="427" to="611" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle> 

<circle cx="90" cy="75" r="4" fill="white">
    <animate id="color1_7" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0.1s;move3_8.end+1.1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_7" attributeName="cx" from="261" to="445" dur="1s" begin="0.1s;move3_8.end+1.1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_7" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_7.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_7" attributeName="cx" from="445" to="445" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_7.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_7" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_8.end+0.1s"/> 
    <animate id="move3_7" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_8.end+0.1s" from="445" to="629" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle>

<circle cx="105" cy="75" r="4" fill="white">
    <animate id="color1_8" attributeName="fill" from="#ffffff" to="#44A0E2" dur="1s" begin="0s;move3_8.end+1s" /> 
    <animate id="move1_8" attributeName="cx" from="279" to="463" dur="1s" begin="0s;move3_8.end+1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0 0.1 0.15 1"/>
    <animate id="color2_8" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#44A0E2" dur="0.6s" begin="color1_8.end" /> 
    <animate id="move2_8" attributeName="cx" from="463" to="463" dur="0.6s" begin="move1_8.end"/>
    <animate id="color3_8" attributeName="fill" from="#44A0E2" to="#ffffff" dur="1s" begin="move2_8.end" /> 
    <animate id="move3_8" attributeName="cx" begin="move2_8.end" from="463" to="647" dur="1s" calcMode="spline" keySplines="0.6 0.1 0.6 1"/>
</circle>
</svg>
```

Link to svg - https://codepen.io/ahremkov/pen/eYKdaRZ

I have another SVG animations, and everything seems fine, so it's not c++ code, something with this SVG file and it's Qt compatibility.
Maybe something with `animate` tag, other SVG animations doesn't use it (its 'animateColor' or 'animateTransform' there).

Comment: What makes you think that Qt supports SMIL?

Comment: Robert Longson, "animateColor" tag and "animateTransform" tag work fine with Qt. Isn't it SMIL?

Comment: animateColor has been deprecated for years, but yes animateTransform is SMIL.

Comment: If it's possible to convert this code to a gif animation, I would take it, it would be much easier that way. But I'm not that good at graphics